# Удаление объкта и освобождение памяти

Tags: c++, указатели

Опишу подробнее, что имею в виду: есть класс, например:

```
class MyClass
{
    //методы и члены
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<MyClass> SHP_MyClass;
```

И есть другой класс:

```
class MyClass2
{
public:
    SHP_MyClass obj;
    //другие методы и члены
};
```

Далее, с каком-то методе MyClass2 я создаю объект MyClass следующим образом:

```
obj.reset(new MyClass(/*параметры*/)); // точнее не создаю, но вы поняли)
```

Теперь сам вопрос: как полностью освободить память выделенную под объект, на который ссылается указатель `obj`, если пользовательский деструктор MyClass отсутствует(т.е. создается по умолчанию)?
При этом, я хочу создать позже опять объект MyClass c указателем на него obj, но так, чтобы не было конфликтов в памяти.

PS дело в том, что в MyClass используется очень кривая сторонняя библиотека. если с shared_ptr так нельзя, есть ли другие смарт-указатели, которые могут?

**UPDATE1:**

```
class CRTPReceive
{
public:
    CRTPReceive(vector<string> input_SDPs, vector<string> IPs, vector<int> my_ports, vector<int> remote_ports)
    { 
        //инициализация
    }
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
private:
    // тут методы в количестве n штук
    //а это свойства, из-под которых хочу освободить память


    vector<AVFormatContext *> out_ifcx;
    vector<AVCodecContext *> out_iccx;

    vector<AVFormatContext *> ifcx;
    vector<AVCodecContext *> iccx;

    vector<SSource> afcx;

    vector<AVFilterGraph *> graphVec;
    vector<AVFilterContext *> sinkVec;

    int tracks;

    vector<SHP_CAVPacket2> rtp;
    vector<SHP_Socket> vecSock;
    vector<udp::endpoint> vecEndpoint;
    vector<string> IPs_;
    vector<int> my_ports_;
    vector<int> remote_ports_;
    uint8_t data[8000];
    ofstream ff1;
    bool on;
    SHP_CAVPacket2 send;
};
```

**UPDATE2:**
Конфликт, например, в функции `avformat_open_input(/*SDP*/)`

Comment: Деструктор по умолчанию `MyClass` полностью (в вашем понимании термина) освобождает все занятые ресурсы (память  и т.п.)? Если да - то вам не о чем беспокоиться, `shared_ptr` его вызовет. Судя по всему, в этом классе нет чего-то особо захватываемого-освобождаемого, так что все должно быть в порядке.

Comment: Насколько большой это класс? Можете привести его объявление, посмотреть конкретнее? И - что за конфликт, как проявляется? хорошо бы какой-то минимально показывающий проблему пример...

Comment: у shared_ptr есть возможность указать deleter. И Ваш объект будет удалятся им.

Comment: Освобождать память должен тот, кто ей владеет. Например, деструктор `std::vector` удалит все объекты, которые хранит. Если вектор хранит указатели, и нужно освобождать память по этим указателям, то либо стоит переделать вектор на `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` вместо `std::vector<T*>`. Либо реализовать освобождение в деструкторе объекта, который является владельцем вектора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос...

Чтобы удалить объект, на который завязан указатель, достаточно выполнить:

```
obj.reset(); // без параметров
```

На самом деле, для `std::shared_ptr` происходит не сразу удаление, а уменьшение кол-ва ссылок на объект. И если оно достигло нуля, то удаляется и сам объект. Подробнее об этом лучше почитать в учебнике по языку.

Если `reset` вызывается с параметрами, то первым аргументом будет новый объект, которым будет владеть этот указатель. Для старого при этом произойдет уменьшение счетчика ссылок. Т.е., например, вызов:

```
obj.reset(new MyClass(/*...*/));
```

По сути равносилен следующим вызовам:

```
auto p = new MyClass(/*...*/);
obj.reset();
obj.reset(p);
```

Здесь стоит обратить внимание на то, что в процессе переустановки (reset) указателя, одновременно существуют 2 объекта `MyClass`. Т.е. сначала создается новый, а потом уже удаляется старый. Иногда такое поведение не подходит (т.к. `MyClass` может  монопольно использовать какой-то ресурс, например сетевой порт), в этом случае при переустановке указателя надо сначала выполнить `reset()` без параметров, а потом уже `reset(<новый объект>)`.

P.S. Если владение объектом под указателем не предполагается разделять с другими `shared_ptr`, то правильнее использовать `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Нет, так не очистилась память...

Comment: @Dmitry ответственность за освобождение ресурсов должна лежать на деструкторе. Почитайте про идиому `RAII`. Если владение/освобождение ресурсом не реализовано правильно - никакие умные указатели Вам не помогут.

Comment: @Dmitry: А **как** вы узнали, что память не очистилась? Вы случайно не заглянули в память через отладчик?

Comment: Структуры типа `AVFilterContext` еще фиг знает, как очистить. Если только присвоить нулевой указатель. Но это не панацея. @VladD не, через диспетчер задач :D

Comment: @Dmitry: Это шутка, или вы серьёзно?